# The salesman randomly pulled out $8$ socks out of $14$ pairs of socks.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The salesman randomly pulled out $8$ socks out of $14$ pairs of socks. Calculate the probability of a case where there is at least one pair of socks among the pulled ones.

My question is: should I be calculating as if all socks were different or as if they form multiset of $14$ elements?

Comment: Work from the complement.  The first choice is free, the second can be any of $26$.  Third can be any of $24$, and so on.

Comment: @lulu that means that all paired socks are different? I kinda feel like you can not separate which is left and which is right, that is why I asked this question in first place.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I'm just saying you have to avoid the pairs that were previously chosen.

Comment: Let's say he selects two choices.  Then the probability that they come from different pairs is just $\frac {26}{27}$, since there are $27$ socks left to choose from and only one bad choice.  That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{28}{8}$ choices of sock, of which $2^8\binom{14}{8}$ don't get both the socks from any one pair, so you want $$1-\frac{2^8\binom{14}{8}}{\binom{28}{8}}=1-\frac{2^8\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{28\cdot27\cdot26\cdot25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22\cdot21}=1-\frac{2^4\cdot2\cdot8}{3\cdot5\cdot23\cdot3}=1-\frac{256}{1035}=\frac{779}{1035}.$$